# Is it possible to make a cgal 3d multi-doamain mesh with no internal segmentation?

Tags: c++, graphics, mesh, cgal, graph-visualization

I am reading the "mesh_implicit_domain" example from [here](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/index.html)

It uses a function wrapper to indicate the union of domains indicated by two functions(these 2 domains intersects and form a larger closed domain). But the cut view nearby on the page shows cgal's algorithm segment the mesh (i.e. clearly depict boundary of the two subdomains indicated by the two functions).  I want a mesh without segmenting the whole model into different regions, simply make mesh for the new larger domain. Is it possible in CGAL?

Comment: I was so sleepy when first start typing this question. Apology for so many typos to those who has already read this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quickly looking at the code, the default constructor defines 2 subdomains which is why you have the boundary between them. Since I don't think the "OR" is implemented in this class.

I see two solutions:
- use only one implicit function and do the "union" directly in the implicit function
- Define your own domain,  starting from [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_3/Mesh_3_2mesh_hybrid_mesh_domain_8cpp-example.html) and in the `In_is_domain()` use the same index for both subdomains.

The first function is clearly the simplest.